# Transcription du [r] de l'API anglais à l'API français

Tags: anglais

J'aimerais savoir s'il y a une façon de transcrire le [r] de l'API anglais avec l'API français ?

Par exemple est-ce que le [r] anglais pourrais, en API français, s'écrire avec un [w] ?

Comment: L'API, c'est l'alphabet phonétique international.  Il n'y a donc pas d'API anglais, français, ou allemand ou autre.  Il n'y en a qu'un.  Je ne comprends pas cette question.

Comment: Ce que j'essaye d'exprimé c'est comment retranscrire le son [r] anglais avec l'api français (je sais j'ai compris : une seul lettre pour un seul son) mais moi sa m'aide à retranscrire les sons anglais en français ; par ex. : away en api s'écrit :  [əˈweɪ] moi pour m'aider à bien prononcé ce mot je l'écris comme suite : [œwɛj] alors bien sûr ce n'est pas la retranscription exact de la prononciation anglais mais moi sa m'aide. Voilà. Donc je cherche à retranscrire la lettre [r] en un son de l'api français qui s'en rapproche (comme [œ] français se rapproche du [ə] anglais).

Answer (score 3):

Les signes de l'alphabet phonétique international (API) permettent de représenter les phonèmes réalisés dans n'importe quelle langue du monde. C'est à dire qu'un même phonème (son) est toujours représenté par le même signe, quelle que soit la langue du mot dans lequel est inclus ce phonème.

Français : rose [ʁoz], ouate [wat]

Anglais :  rose [ɹəʊz], water ['wɔːtə]

Allemand : rot [ʁoːt]

Chaque langue n'utilise qu'un nombre limité de sons et donc tous les phonèmes ne sont pas présents dans toutes les langues.  Par exemple l'anglais n'ayant pas de voyelles nasales, on n'utilise pas les signes /ɔ̃/ et /ɑ̃/ en anglais. Le signe représentant la consonne dentale /ð/ n'est pas utilisé en français qui n'a pas ce son mais il est utilisé en anglais et en espagnol (entre autres).

Comment: Le "r" allemand est réalisé chez la plupart des Allemands comme le "r" français.  Je transcrirais "rot",  [ʁo:t].

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse.